# How to tie NSWindow to another NSWindow?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

These two delegates method are called either before a NSWindow has started to move, or after the NSWindow has stopped to move.

```
-(void)windowWillMove:(NSNotification *)notification 
-(void)windowDidMove:(NSNotification *)notification
```

How can I reposition another NSWindow *while* the first NSWindow is moving ? I want to simulate a kind of physical extension of the NSWindow, and it should not lag behind while the window is being dragged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `addChildWindow:ordered:` and `setParentWindow:` in `NSWindow`:

[NSWindow Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This works great for changes in the position, but it's lagging when I resize the main window, and have to reposition the child window.